# Using Phil Sturgeon's Rest Server for login using a login form

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to use Phil Sturgeon's Rest Server in Codeigniter but having problem with user validation. How can I use array of username and password for login using a login form?

Comment: By posting it to the API, and having it return success + Users API key??

Comment: thanks for the help